# Android: SlidingDrawer like the one in the Android main window

Tags: android, handle, slidingdrawer

I implemented a SlidingDrawer in my app and everything works fine so far.

Then I made an invisible handle, just like the one in the Android main window.

Now I want, that it is possible to grab the handle (and make it visible) just by moving the finger over the handle. I mean the same behaviour like the one in the Android main window.

But i don´t know how to mange that. 
(At the moment it only works when you tap at the handle, and not if you tap somewhere else and move the finger above the handle)

Comment: Make your handle to fill the width of the screen and let me know.

Comment: Then the well known swipe gesture will not be possible. Just a single click.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a bad idea. There will be no way to distinquish between the system's drawer and your app's drawer.

Comment: Maybe @user1786426 will have the sliding drawer somewhere else other than the top of the screen?

Comment: My app runs fullscreen, so there will be no system´s drawer.

Comment: Oh. So it is going to be graphically driven application? In which case you probably won't be using standard UI toolkit.

Comment: Yes partly. But at this point I have to use standart UI. I just downloaded the Android source code to look how they have done it. But it´s hard to find the right classes.

Answer (score 0):

You want to detect a [swipe motion](http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/gestures.html) that starts on the top bezel.

You want to use MotionEvent's [getEdgeFlags()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html#getEdgeFlags%28%29) to detect whether a swipe gesture starts on the bezel.